# Calculating box quantities T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to calculate box quantities/minimum order quantities and need a little help.

If say I have a required quantity of 386 but the box quantity is 500 I would need to return 500 as the order quantity

like wise if the required quantity is 540 and the box quantity is 500 I would need to return 1000 as the order quantity

I need this to be in SQL

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Schema of table(s) involved and example data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple reusable function for calculating box quantities.

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_CalculateBoxQuantity
(
    @RequiredAmount INT,
    @BoxQuantity INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ret INT

    SET @Ret = @BoxQuantity * CEILING((CAST(@RequiredAmount AS DECIMAL(20,10)) / CAST(@BoxQuantity AS DECIMAL(20,10))))

    RETURN @Ret  
END
```

Comment: It seems resource inefficient to use typecasting and ceiling when using integer division could do the same trick. Also scalar functions don't work very well with set logic so if you want a reusable function that works well with sets then you should make it a table valued function (with one row and one column) so that you can use CROSS APPLY.

Comment: Plug and play - Perfect

David , Thanks for your solution and the suggestions with the above however I am not applying this to 10 trillion rows so performance is negligible

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

I would solve it like this, try it out with different values of @reqQuantity to see how it works.

```
DECLARE @reqQuantity INT = 386
,@boxSize INT = 500
SELECT CASE WHEN @reqQuantity % @boxSize = 0 THEN @reqQuantity ELSE (@reqQuantity/@boxSize+1)*@boxSize END AS OrderQuantity
```